# is there a way to override model methods in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-testing

I have a model like this:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField('date added', auto_now_add=True)
    modify_date = models.DateTimeField('date modified', auto_now=True)
    ...

    def last_tracked_location(self):
        ...
        try:
            url = 'myurl'
            return requests.get(
                url,
            ).json()['location'])
        except:
            return False
```

This method get's called later for the admin's panel. It requests something from an api and then returns either this or false.

In testing mode the other api doesn't exist so the request delays all the tests till it timeouts and then returns `False`.

Is there a way to override this? I checked the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings) but could only find out to override the settings.

Another idea I had was to test inside the method if it's being called in testing mode and then just never go into this try block. But I don't think this is a clean way.

*UPDATE*

I am calling the tests like so:

`python3 manage.py test --settings=app.settings_test`

Comment: Can you please include which test suite you are using, e.g. `django.test`?

Comment: Your update doesn't really answer the question but I assume you are using `django.test`.
Without an example of your actual test, it is really difficult to help you, but I have included an example of a mock below. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your tests so that they mock the response of the API. The [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#module-unittest.mock) module is a good starting point and part of the Python standard library since Python 3.3.

I don't have access to your full code but here is an example to get you started:

```
from unittest import mock
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import Car


@mock.patch('yourapp.models.Car.last_tracked_location')
class CarTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_get_last_tracked_location(self, mock_last_tracked_location):
        mock_last_tracked_location.return_value = {'location': 'Paris'}
        car = Car.objects.create()
        response = car.last_tracked_location()
        assert response['location'] == 'Paris'
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking DEBUG directly in method is not pretty clean in my opinion.
Maybe it will be better for you to write some API class for making this request?

Then you can either write separate logic for this class to run in 'testing mode' (not sure i understand correctly what do you mean by that :) test env ?) or just create mock in tests.

Here you can read more about conditionally testing scenarios:
https://realpython.com/testing-third-party-apis-with-mocks/